# How to interpolate (or map) 2D data onto a regular homogeneous grid (Eg; 250x250) in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm struggling to interpolate a two 1D arrays in to a regular 2D grid.

```
A = 
[[ 193.05  192.55  192.06 ...,  191.21  190.73  190.26]
 [ 193.05  192.55  192.06 ...,  191.21  190.73  190.26]
 [ 193.05  192.55  192.06 ...,  191.21  190.73  190.26]
 ..., 
 [ 193.05  192.55  192.06 ...,  191.21  190.73  190.26]
 [ 193.05  192.55  192.06 ...,  191.21  190.73  190.26]
 [ 193.05  192.55  192.06 ...,  191.21  190.73  190.26]]

B = 
[ 12.907  16.158  19.419  22.688  25.967  29.255  32.552  35.857  39.171
  42.493  45.824  49.163  52.509  55.863  59.225  62.594  65.969  69.352
  69.352  69.352  72.741  76.137  79.539  12.689  15.883  19.086  22.296
  25.515  28.742  31.977  35.22   38.47   41.728  44.993  48.265  51.544
  54.829  58.122  61.42   64.725  68.035  68.035  68.035  71.352  74.673
  78.     12.479  15.618  18.765  21.919  25.08   28.249  31.424  34.607
  37.796  40.992  44.194  47.402  50.617  53.837  57.063  60.295  63.532
  66.774  66.774  66.774  70.02   73.272  76.528]
```

When they're plotted, looks like this:

[image: A vs B scatter plot]

Please note that there are multiple values for each 'x' value.. (as you can see from the above plot)

I want to interpolate that data on to a uniform mesh like grid with equal scales..(250x250)

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have only just found this so a bit late. I am now facing a similar problem. Before I try to come up with a solution, did you ever solve it yourself? If not, what have you tried so far?